# Disable Angular CLI auto generation of templates and ng generate component command shows error "style is not defined"

Tags: angular, templates, styles, command-line-interface

Problem 1:
When i'm creating a new module with Angular CLI Version 7.3.8 with the command ng g m user --routing Angular auto generates templates for the user-routing.module.ts and user.module.ts file

[module creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq1ep.png)

Problem 2:
When i'm creating a new component with ng g c user/component/users it throws an error saying "style is not defined"

[component creating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtTuG.png)

I tried:

1. Updating Angular CLI to the latest version
2. Downgrading Angular CLI to a version which works on another PC
3. Uninstalling Angular CLI and reinstalling it again
4. Delete npm and npm-cache folders in roaming